# Spring boot application utilizes 100% CPU

Tags: java, spring-boot

We have springboot application. When we tried doing loadtesting of our application, it's CPU goes beyond 100% (Overall Max 101%).

We are measuring CPU Utilization using docker stats command. So for 2 core it should use maximum  200. If Docker stats show 200, that means it is using 100% of both cores. Our Application uses 200/200 (Means 100%).

**Resource Details**:

CPU - 2 Core

JVM Memory Size - 2GB

**Versions**:

java - Openjdk11

Springboot - 2.2.0.RELEASE

We are doing loadtesting using Jmeter Plan.

**Jmeter Strategy is**:

Threads - 5

Total Request per Minute to Application - 60,000

Total Request per Second to Application - 1000

Average Response time of application is - 4ms

In our Loadtesting, we Observed below

**CPU Utilization statistics(One of the Snapshot)**:

5 Tomcat Runnable Threads - Total CPU - 45% (Docker stats - 90/200)

5 Tomcat Waiting Threads - Total CPU - 40% (Docker stats - 80/200)

In addition to above, below JVM threads take maximum CPUs. Due to below threads also, CPU goes very high.

C2 CompilerThread0 (Highest CPU)

DestroyJavaVM

C1 CompilerThread0

Now in  general, CPU Goes very high for two reasons.

1. Constant GC - (There are no Full GC in our Application)
2. Looping in application - (There is no looping found in our Application)

Now to mitigate above CPU spike, we did following activity but got same CPU Utilization(100%).

1. Upgraded Springboot version from 2.2.0 to 2.3.1 (Suggested by one of the Stackoverflow thread)
2. Also used Oracle JDK 8 instead of OpenJDK11 to reduce C1 and C2 compiler Thread Utilization.
3. Changed Springboot Embedded tomcat to undertow.

Are we missing any configuration? Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: There is far too little information and the problem too broad to even attempt to answer such a question.

Comment: Try to downgrade the version of tomcat. Refer to this : http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/High-CPU-Consumption-with-Tomcat-8-5-4-NIO-and-SSL-td5054445.html for details.

Comment: Is it an application from scratch or there is some extra code/functional?

Comment: Our Application is from scratch.

Comment: For testing, we have done one more thing. We added return statement from controller itself. Still it uses full CPU

Comment: Can you use Java Flight Recorder to narrow the bottleneck?

Comment: And what does your controller do? Can you show some code?

Comment: Controller only returns true. Single line of Code.